# Why does this loop break even if the condition is true?

Tags: python

I made a simple Tic Tac Toe game by using dictionaries in python from Automate the boring stuff with python. The while loop should break when the conditions match. But it keeps going.

I tried replacing "and" operators with "or" and the loop breaks on the first run. What's wrong with it? Why does the loop not break even if the condition satisfy?

---

```
theBoards = {'A' : ' ', 'B': ' ', 'C' : ' ',
            'D' : ' ', 'E' : ' ', 'F' : ' ',
            'G' : ' ', 'H': ' ', 'I': ' '}


def drawBoard(theBoard):
    print(theBoard['A'] + '|' + theBoard['B'] + '|' + theBoard['C'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(theBoard['D'] + '|' + theBoard['E'] + '|' + theBoard['F'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(theBoard['G'] + '|' + theBoard['H'] + '|' + theBoard['I'])

drawBoard(theBoards)    
turn = 'X'
while True:
    move = input("Where do you want your " + turn + ': ')
    theBoards[move] = turn
    drawBoard(theBoards)

    if(     theBoards['A'] == theBoards['B'] == theBoards['C']
        and theBoards['D'] == theBoards['E'] == theBoards['F']
        and theBoards['G'] == theBoards['H'] == theBoards['I']
        and theBoards['A'] == theBoards['D'] == theBoards['G']
        and theBoards['B'] == theBoards['E'] == theBoards['H']
        and theBoards['C'] == theBoards['F'] == theBoards['I']
        and theBoards['A'] == theBoards['E'] == theBoards['I']
        and theBoards['C'] == theBoards['E'] == theBoards['G']):
        print("Winner is " + turn)
        break
    if turn  == 'X':
        turn = 'O'
    else:
        turn = 'X'
```

Comment: You should use `or`. You don't want ALL those conditions to be `True`. However, most of the conditions are going to be met after the first move since all but one position is `'  '`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions should be connected with `or`, not `and`, since you win tic-tac-toe by making any 3 in a row. With `and` *every* 3 in a row must be the same.

The reason it's ending after the first turn is because you're not checking that the cells are actually filled in. So an empty row, column, or diagonal will be considered to be a match, because all the spaces are equal to each other.

Instead of just checking that they're equal to each other, check that they're equal to `turn`.

```
    if(    theBoards['A'] == theBoards['B'] == theBoards['C'] == turn
        or theBoards['D'] == theBoards['E'] == theBoards['F'] == turn
        or theBoards['G'] == theBoards['H'] == theBoards['I'] == turn
        or theBoards['A'] == theBoards['D'] == theBoards['G'] == turn
        or theBoards['B'] == theBoards['E'] == theBoards['H'] == turn
        or theBoards['C'] == theBoards['F'] == theBoards['I'] == turn
        or theBoards['A'] == theBoards['E'] == theBoards['I'] == turn
        or theBoards['C'] == theBoards['E'] == theBoards['G'] == turn):
```